# jboss throws out of memory: heap space while running in intellij idea but not when running in eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, intellij-idea, jboss

Up until a merge of a branch into trunk earlier this week which updated a large portion of the common code, my IntelliJ IDEA JBOSS configuration was working fine.  Now when the application runs a query that returns a large amount of data, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getCharBuffer(PhysicalConnection.java:7018)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareAccessors(OracleStatement.java:907)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receiveCommon(T4CTTIdcb.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIdcb.receive(T4CTTIdcb.java:127)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:992)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:791)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:866)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doScrollExecuteCommon(OracleStatement.java:4219)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.doScrollPstmtExecuteUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9517)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3431)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)
```

Oddly enough, this seems very specific to querying oracle and returning large amounts of data. I've tried anything I could find regarding increasing the heap size to alleviate the issue, but even setting the max for the application in the VM options to 4GB and the max for the IDE to 8GB does nothing.

Most of our team uses Eclipse as an IDE and haven't seen this issue pop up, so I downloaded the most recent eclipse and got the project pulled in and configured to run with the same values (except the original heap size max for the VM options) and it works fine.

Can anyone tell me what could possibly be causing the out of memory solely when running the application through IntelliJ IDEA?  It's driving me crazy, I'd rather not have to switch IDEs just to run the application locally and attach a debugger to monitor values in memory, so if anyone could provide any insight or additional steps to try, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: First of all I would recommend you to reread your question one more time and decide on where jboss runs OK and where it crashes as a result of OOM exception. Right now when I read it - the title of the question says that it crashes in intellij idea, and in the second paragraph of the question itself it says " the application works fine when running JBOSS through IntelliJ". Then you say that it works fine for most members of the team again, and then you say that when you installed last version of eclipse it throws OOME for you. And then you say again that it throws OOME in intellij idea.

Comment: My mistake -- I meant to say it runs fine in Eclipse.  I must've missed that after rewording things in the original post.  Sorry about that.  I've removed the confusing sentence, but for clarity: since the common code for the application was updated, IntelliJ has the OOME when dealing with dbcursors, running the same code in eclipse with the same JBOSS options works fine.

Comment: Ok, now the question looks fine. Since you are running the app on jboss server under two different IDEs it could mean that you even run them with different java versions. (8vs 11 or vs 14 for example)
As a first step in analyst of the issue I would check the jvm versions that used when you run JBOSS from eclipse and from Intellij idea. The next step would be related to checking classpath and moduleversions under the jboss. 
What I would do I would configure THE SAME jboss installation instance for both IDEs first (if it is not like that yet). Take those actions and provide feedback please.

Comment: Also what is used to BUILD the project before deploying it to the JBOSS instance? maven or gradle or original ides builders or something else? :) Perhaps the WARs that is produced by these two different IDEs - are different. As another step in diagnosing the issue - I would try to run the produced by these two IDES's WAR's on vanilla JBOSS that is not executed BY the IDE, but just run it solely and try to deploy WAR's that are produced by different IDEs (but firstly answer the question what is used to build the WAR).

Comment: crank up jconsole, attach to each jboss server instance and look at the JVM parameters.  jconsole is in the jboss bin folder.  or look in the jboss log file for startup parameter values.

Comment: I checked the settings for both JBOSS servers, they are both set to use the project JRE which is AdoptOpenJDK 8.0.222.10 -- both IDEA and Eclipse should be as close to identical as possible, as when I moved to IDEA 1.5 years ago, I used the Eclipse setup as a template to move all settings. Both are using JBOSS 4.2.3 GA, pointing to the same directory the build deploys to. Build is via ANT, run outside of the IDEs, so anything build related should be *exactly* the same. The server runs and I'm able to create new data records, it's just loading the dbcursor in that method that triggers the OOME.

Comment: Ok, so build is performed by ant. And it produces the WAR, and the part I did not understand is - Did you try to run JBOS server not from IDE, but just as a standalone server from pure bash and then deploy war to that standalone instance? Does it lead to OOME on standalone JBOS running instance?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I couldn't find jconsole in the build output directory, but I can check anything from the jmx-console to see what the values are if that helps in any way.

Comment: @Pasha that's a good idea and I wanted to see what would happen; I fully expected it to behave like I'd started it through Eclipse but to my surprise, the OOME occurred in the same spot I've been seeing it as if I'd started the server through IDEA instead of via the CLI...

Comment: I'm not saying it is different jvms.  it is the startup properties of each jvm in the particular IDE.  jconsole is in $JBOSS_HOME/bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that we were pulling down 2 versions of ojdbc via our ivy file after the merge down on Monday, so I asked the programmer in charge of the migration to the updated common code about it and I tried excluding the older version, but this wasn't a full solution to the multiple versions of jdbc drivers.  The other programmer pursued cleaning up the ivy file to remove the dependencies for jdbc6 and only use the latest version of jdbc8... this resolved the issue.

Thank you all for your help, I'm not sure I would've noticed the ojdbc jar issue if it wasn't for y'all...

I'm still curious as to what the difference between standalone/IDEA and Eclipse was that Eclipse was able to deal with the driver conflict while the others threw the OOME.

Comment:  Glad you have figured that out. Good job. Up to the difference in behavior between when you run jboss from under IDE's... I can't tell you why it was happening that way... :)